# PHP's array_merge_recursive behaviour on integer keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there an approach for recursively merging arrays, in the same way as PHP's `array_merge_recursive()` function does, *except* that integer keys are treated the same as string keys?

(It's important for the process that the keys remain parse-able as integers.)

**For example:**

```
$a = array(
    'a' => array(1)
);
$b = array(
    'a' => array(2, 3)
);
var_dump(array_merge_recursive($a, $b));
```

Will merge the on the `"a"` key and output, as expected, the following:

```
array(1) {
    ["a"] => array(3) {
        [0] => int(1)
        [1] => int(2)
        [2] => int(3)
    }
}
```

However, when using integers for keys (even when as a string):

```
$a = array(
    '123' => array(1)
);
$b = array(
    '123' => array(2, 3)
);
var_dump(array_merge_recursive($a, $b));
```

`array_merge_recursive()` will return:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => array(3) {
        [0] => int(1)
    }
    [1] => array(2) {
        [0] => int(2)
        [1] => int(3)
    }
}
```

Instead of the much desired:

```
array(1) {
    ["123"] => array(3) {
        [0] => int(1)
        [1] => int(2)
        [2] => int(3)
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can prefix the array keys with a short string:

```
function addPrefix($a) {
    return '_' . $a;
}
# transform keys
$array1 = array_combine(array_map('addPrefix', array_keys($array1)), $array1);
$array2 = array_combine(array_map('addPrefix', array_keys($array2)), $array2);
# call array_combine
$array = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
# reverse previous operation  
function stripPrefix($a) {
     return substr($a, 1);
}
$array = array_combine(array_map('stripPrefix', array_keys($array)), $array)
```

Comment: While this is correct it feels too contrived. Why not a regular loop instead?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using soulmerge's idea of converting the keys by adding a string. My new function can only handle 2 parameters, however, but that was the case you had, so that's what I went with. Have a look.

```
// Adds a _ to top level keys of an array
function prefixer($array) {
    $out = array();
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $out['_' . $k] = $v;
    }
    return $out;
}
// Remove first character from all keys of an array
function unprefixer($array) {
    $out = array();
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $newkey = substr($k,1);
        $out[$newkey] = $v;
    }
    return $out;
}
// Combine 2 arrays and preserve the keys
function array_merge_recursive_improved($a, $b) {
    $a = prefixer($a);
    $b = prefixer($b);
    $out = unprefixer(array_merge_recursive($a, $b));
    return $out;
}
```

And what's out sample data look like?

```
// some sample data    
$a = array(
    '123' => array(1)
);
$b = array(
    '123' => array(2, 3)
);

// what do the results say:    
print_r($a);
// Array
// (
//     [123] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 1
//         )
// 
// )

print_r($b);
// Array
// (
//     [123] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 2
//             [1] => 3
//         )
// 
// )
```

And let's try them out:

```
print_r(array_merge_recursive($a, $b));
// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 1
//         )
// 
//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 2
//             [1] => 3
//         )
// 
// )

print_r(array_merge_recursive_improved($a, $b));
// Array
// (
//     [123] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 1
//             [1] => 2
//             [2] => 3
//         )
// 
// )
```

Comment: Your `prefixer` and `unprefixer` functions need to verify if the value is an array ! For instance, in the `prefixer`, you need to have `if (is_array($v))
  {
   $out['_' . $k] = prefixer($v);
  }
  else
  {
   $out['_' . $k] = $v;
  }` inside the loop. Otherwise it's working great !

Answer (score 0):

If you want the keys to be treated as strings just make it strings adding a prefix when you fill it, instead of to fill it with numbers and then refill another array just to order it.

Answer (score 0):

This recursive array merge function doesn't renumber integer keys and appends new values to existing ones OR adds a new [key => value] pair if the pair doesn't exist. I suppose and exen sure, that this function is that what you need.

```
function array_merge_recursive_adv(array &$array1, $array2) {
        if(!empty($array2) && is_array($array2))
            foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
                    if(array_key_exists($key,$array1)) {
                        if(is_array($value)){
                            array_merge_recursive_adv($array1[$key], $value);
                        } else {
                             if(!empty($array1[$key])) {
                                if(is_array($array1[$key])){
                                    array_push($array1[$key], $value);
                                } else {
                                    $array1[$key] = [$array1[$key]];
                                    $array1[$key][] = $value;
                                }
                             } else if(empty($array1[$key])) {
                                $array1[$key] = $value;
                             }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $array1[$key] = $value;
                    }
            }
            return $array1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge_recursive()` simply isn't the right tool for merging two 2d array with numeric first level keys.

Use a standard loop to merge the second array's values into the first array on the related first level key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/onXcQ))

```
foreach ($b as $k => $v) {
    $a[$k] = array_merge($a[$k] ?? [], $v);
}
var_export($a);
```