# merging of two array in php, duplicate gets removed

Tags: php

I looking to merge the following array in PHP

```
array 1 = 
[0] 
    (
        [roll_id] => 1
        [vendor_id] => 1
    )
[1] 
    (
        [roll_id] => 2
        [vendor_id] => 1
    )

Array 2 = 
[0]         
   (
        [roll_id] => 1
        [roll_name] => Manager
        [roll_discription] => 
    )
[1] 
    (
        [roll_id] => 2
        [roll_name] => Store Leader
        [roll_discription] => 
    )
```

such that

```
Array 3 = 
 [0]    
   (
        [roll_id] => 1
        [roll_name] => Manager
        [roll_discription] => 
        [vendor_id] => 1
    )

[1] 
    (
        [roll_id] => 2
        [roll_name] => Store Leader
        [roll_discription] =>
        [vendor_id] => 1 
    )
```

I understand using loop I can do this, was looking to use some inbuilt function like array_merge, array_unique.

Comment: Hi rajiv. I don't think there is such function to achive such type of result. You must use loop to achive your result. Even you can refer this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541598/merging-two-arrays-by-index