# Join multiple array in Laravel 7 or PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, merge, laravel-7

I have 3 array below from html textbox `txt_job_exp_start[]`, `txt_job_exp_end[]` ,`txt_job_exp_desc[]` and i want to join them together using laravel 7 or any method.

```
array:3 [▼
  "txt_job_exp_start" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "2019-03"
    1 => "2018-12"
    2 => "2017-12"
  ]
  "txt_job_exp_end" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "2020-02"
    1 => "2019-11"
    2 => "2018-08"
  ]
  "txt_job_exp_desc" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Description 1"
    1 => "Description 2"
    2 => "Description 3"
  ]
]
```

This is the result i want. please kindly help me.

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "start" => "2019-03"
    "end"  => "2020-02"
    "description"  => "Description 1"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "start"  => "2018-12"
    "end"  => "2019-11"
    "description"  => "Description 2"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "start"  => "2017-12"
    "end"  => "2018-08"
    "description"  => "Description 3"
  ]
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541598/merging-two-arrays-by-index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging two arrays by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541598/merging-two-arrays-by-index)

Comment: Laravel doesnt replace PHP. You can join arrays without it. Any code attempt because I'm seeing a data structure?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map` with first value of `null` to *zip* as many arrays as you want as stated in [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Below code may help you.

```
$txt_job_exp_start = [];
$txt_job_exp_end = [];
$txt_job_exp_desc = [];

$result = array_map(null, $txt_job_exp_start, $txt_job_exp_end, $txt_job_exp_desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have that array just run a loop through it and store the values in an empty array.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $arr2[] = $val;
}
var_dump($arr2);
```

demo [here](https://3v4l.org/NIq2o)